# Angularjs Route Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr]

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-routing

I've a problem with route angularjs. When open the browser to see a page don't see the view, in the console I've this message[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oz97O.png)

controller.js

```
angular.module('contactMgr',['ngRoute'])
.controller('AppCtrl',function ($scope,$http){
     // Controller for index.html
}
.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.when('/',{
                           controller: 'indexCtrl',
                           templateUrl: 'assets/partials/index.html'
                      })
                .when('/add-contact',{
                           controller: 'addCtrl',
                           templateUrl: 'assets/partials/add.html'
                      });
   })
.controller('indexCtrl',function($scope){
})

.controller('addCtrl',function($scope){
});
```

index.html (not assets/partials/index.html)

```
<div class="container">
  <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
```

I use:

jquery-3.1.1.min.js

angular.min.js v1.2.32

angular-route.min.js

Thanks!

I'VE SOLVED THE PROBLEM!

I imported the min.js, i change angular.min.js and angular-route.min.js with angular.js and angular-route.js and work fine, but i don't understand why... In one site i read that is because are min file but i dont' understand how do work with min file.

Comment: Did you include all you script files (angular, etc) in your project resources?

Comment: yes! I've all in my project folder

Comment: I don't understand either since I've done many project with minified files and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You have not close the route configuration,

```
var app = angular.module("contactMgr", ['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
  when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'main.html',
    controller: 'indexCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'homeCtrl'
  }).
  when('/contact', {
    templateUrl: 'contact.html',
    controller: 'addCtrl',
    controllerAs: ''
  })

  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });

}])
app.controller('indexCtrl', function($scope) {

});
app.controller('addCtrl', function($scope) {

});
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/6eSUYcaFEzAZkExKN5KR?p=preview)**

Comment: Not, works fine enough if not declare the var app. The problem is in the import of the angular e angular-route, i imported the min but i had to be imported the uncompressed file. But i don't understand why...